# Is pam_krb5 affected by Active Directory kerberos changes due to CVE-2021-42287?

Tags: linux, pam, active-directory, kerberos

I use pam_krb5 to authenticate Linux users against a Microsoft Active Directory.  Due to CVE-2021-42287, Microsoft is pushing out updates that will change the way kerberos works in AD.  Microsoft's description of the problem and mitigation is here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb5008380-authentication-updates-cve-2021-42287-9dafac11-e0d0-4cb8-959a-143bd0201041

The update will set PacRequestorEnforcement to 1 in Active Directory, causing AD to add "new information about the original requestor to the PACs of Kerberos Ticket-Granting Tickets".

I see that these changes have an impact on Linux computers that join an AD domain:

https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6645871

but it's not clear to me whether these changes will affect pam_krb5.  Has anyone tested this?